# int pointer referencing data

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

In the following piece of code ( i changed this a little ) suppose `row` is *15*. The question is, does the`&data[row >> 6]` is referencing to an address outside of its nomimal address value ?

```
    uint64_t volatile *data;
    int numRows = 45;

    numWords = (numRows + 63) >> 6;
    data= new uint64_t[numWords];
    memset((void*)data, 0, sizeof(uint64_t) * numWords);

    int row = 15;
    uint64_t bit = 1LL << (row & 63);
    Or64(&data[row >> 6], bit);
```

Running a modified code I noticed that `&data[1]` points to starting address *+8*, `&data[2]` starting address *+16* and so on.

So, If starting address of the data variable (64bit length) is 0x00000001 where referene `&data[row >> 6]` should point to ?

The code above is supposed to change some bits inside the data variable, how to explain this ?

Comment: The code doesn't make sense to me. `data` is uninitialized, so it's UB to apply `[]` to it.

Comment: If row =512, `row >> 6` will result in 32768. This means you are looking at `&data[32768]`. The size of `uint64_t` should be 8 unless your target system is quite unusual, but lets go with the 4 bytes you've measured. You should get 0x00000001 + 32768 * 4 or 0x00000001  + 131072. Is this out of range? Maybe. Not enough information here to tell. By the way, `row & 63` is `0x200&0x3F`. None of the bits match, so the result will be 0, so `bit` will just be 1.

Comment: @user4581301. If row is 512 then row >> 6 (right shift) is 8 and not 32768. Suppose that data us already initialized with something.

Comment: I changed the code to make it more readable

Comment: <expletive deleted). Read that the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a closer look now it seems pretty clear.
The code just set some bits inside an int 64bit value as a mask array flag.

In a single 64bit number we can have 64 different bit flags positions, BUT if we need more flags position than this number, then we have to take one more 64bit number side by side. The `data= new uint64_t[numWords];` allocates such  numbers of 64bit integers as it is shown by the quotient of the `numwords` / 64 division (shifting right by 1 is equal with a division by 2).

Now, To access  the right 64bit mask array we do almost the same thing. First we try to find in which 64bit array flag belongs the given `row` number. If row > 63 then is laying to a next 64bit bit mask array ( a number bigger than 63 and smaller than 128 that is shifting right by 6 it returns 0 ). After that we can set the appropriate bit flag.